# Unable to install package in Ansible

Tags: php, ansible, yum

I have an Ansible script that fail to install some package.

Here is the relevant code from the script.

```
  - name: Install php-cli
    yum:
      name: php70-php-cli
      state: present
```

When the Ansible playbook run, there is no error regarding this line. However, this package hasn't been installed on the server at all.

What could be the issue? Is there any way to debug it?

Edit - Here is the playbook's output:

```
ok: [10.x.x.x] => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["php70-php-cli-7.0.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 providing php70-php-cli is already installed"]}
```

Comment: Run playbook at least with `-vv` verbosity and paste task output to your question.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Done.

Comment: `sudo yum list installed | grep php70` (on the target)

Comment: I get `php70-php-cli.x86_64                  7.0.9-1.el7.remi                @remi-safe`. Does Ansible's yum module install dependencies as well?

Comment: So where does the claim "*However, this package hasn't been installed on the server at all.*" come from?

Comment: Because when i try to install the package manually, i don't get a massage of "already installed...nothing to do". Instead of this, i get a list of packages to install, like it was never was installed at all. Does Ansible's yum module install dependencies as well?

Comment: If you finished trying to install the package, you would get the same output that Ansible is giving.

Comment: Guys, could the problem related to GPG key? Do i need to import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your issue is related to the difference in `state: present` vs `state: latest`.

It looks like the yum module with `state: present` checks the rpmdb to see if the pkg exists and does nothing further.

Since your manual install seems to indicate you have some addition dependencies or updates related to your package, try running with `state: latest` which internally will run a `yum check-update` and see if this pulls those files in.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I already changed it to `latest` it worked great.